# INSERT and RETURNING multiple values SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables where relationship one to many, and I want INSERT to `mytable` some values and RETURNING multiple values INTO variables to use them later. Here example:

```
 IF NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE label_id = xxx)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO mytable
        (label_id, "name")
        VALUES
        (xxx,'foo'),
        (xxx,'bar')
    RETURNING 
        (SELECT id INTO mytable_id1 FROM mytable WHERE name = 'foo'),
        (SELECT id INTO mytable_id2 FROM mytable WHERE name = 'bar');
    ELSE 
        (SELECT id INTO mytable_id1 FROM mytable WHERE name = 'foo'),
        (SELECT id INTO mytable_id2 FROM mytable WHERE name = 'bar');
 END IF;
```

But I get always error:

> ERROR: INTO specified more than once at or near "into"

I trying google problem and for example [INSERT INTO ... RETURNING multiple columns (PostgreSQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508387/insert-into-returning-multiple-columns-postgresql) and [Error: INTO specified more than once at or near "INTO"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803586/error-into-specified-more-than-once-at-or-near-into)

unfortunately solutions it doesn't help for me (or I do something wrong). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I went the other way and a separate `IF` for each variable. Not very smart **but its work**

```
 IF NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE label_id = xxx and "name"='foo')
    THEN
        INSERT INTO mytable
        (label_id, "name")
        VALUES
        (xxx,'foo'),
    RETURNING 
        (SELECT id INTO mytable_id1 FROM mytable WHERE name = 'foo');
    ELSE 
        (SELECT id INTO mytable_id1 FROM mytable WHERE name = 'foo');
 END IF;
 IF NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE label_id = xxx and "name"='bar')
    THEN
        INSERT INTO mytable
        (label_id, "name")
        VALUES
        (xxx,'bar'),
    RETURNING 
        (SELECT id INTO mytable_id1 FROM mytable WHERE name = 'bar');
    ELSE 
        (SELECT id INTO mytable_id1 FROM mytable WHERE name = 'bar');
 END IF;
```